# Postgres trigger has no effect despite running

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have a trigger that updates a count in table `rssfeeds` whenever an `insert` occurs on table `articles`.

Here is what the function looks like:

```
UPDATE rssfeeds
    SET total_articles = total_articles + 1
    FROM feed_articles
    WHERE feed_articles.articleid = NEW.articleid
    AND rssfeeds.rowid = feed_articles.feedid;
```

The function takes an article id and looks for a corresponding feed inside the `feed_articles` table then takes that feed id and uses it to update `total_articles` in the `rssfeeds` table.

Everythings runs but the `total_articles` column is never changed.

Here is what I've done:

- Verified the `NEW.articleid` has a valid articleid.
- Verified that the function updates `total_articles` if I run it directly in a normal query.
- Verified that the trigger is triggered on `insert` as it should.

If I modify the above function so that instead of `NEW.articleid` I use a number of an article id, it works!

What am I missing here?

Comment: You may want to explain how exactly you verified what you say you verified (except perhaps the obvious case of the update outside the trigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The `articleid` is being used before the `feed_articles` table is updated so the trigger function can not find a corresponding feed for the article.
I probably should move that logic that updates the `feed_articles` to a trigger too. Rookie mistake.